# How to append stylesheets in laravel email

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to send an email when user submits a form in laravel. So in my Controller I have :

```
Mail::to($request->to)->send(new \App\Mail\ShareEbol());
```

And in my `ShareEBOL` class, in build method I have:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('panel.reports.ebol');
}
```

And in my `ebol.blade.php` file I have:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <h2 class="my-custom-header"> Hello World </h2>
    <p class="my-custom-paragraph"> some text... </p>

@endsection
```

And in my `layouts.app` blade file I have appended some stylesheets :

```
<link href="{{asset('assets/css/custom.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Email is sent successfuly, but the problem is css styles that I have included in `custom.css` are not applied in email. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to embed the style directly withing `<style>...</style>` . Email clients tend to block the stylesheets that come from links

Comment: like @apokryfos said, you will want to use <style> tags in the email.  Here is an example from Foundation https://github.com/foundation/foundation-emails/blob/develop/templates/newsletter.html

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner

Comment: @eylay check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64365687/14475852) if might help.

Answer (score 3):

### ****Steps to customize css**** - *Markdown Mailables*

It seems that you had created your custom ui. so I try to help based on your custom need.

---

**Option 1:**

1. Create path `html/themes`. *for example*: `resources/views/panel/reports/ebol/html/themes`
2. copy your `custom.css` to `html/themes`
3. edit `config/mail.php` like below:

   ```
   ...

   'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'custom', // custom.css

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/panel/reports/ebol'),
    ],
   ```

   ],

*Now default theme for all markdowns will be `custom.css`*

---

**Option 2:**

another option is to set the theme using `$theme` property of mailable class instead of setting that in `config/mail.php`

*for example:*

```
class ShareEbol extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $theme = 'custom'; // custom.css

...
```

---

**Option 3:**

another option is to use `Mail Notifications` that is well documented here : [Laravel Mail Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#mail-notifications)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Laravel ***Markdown Mailables***. Which gives you the ability to use theme and also you can customise these themes or you can create you own theme.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#markdown-mailables

**Step 1 -** Generate a Markdown Mailables with blade file using following command.

```
php artisan make:mail ShareEbol --markdown=emails.panel.reports.ebol
```

This will create your Mail Function and blade also. You can update the function as per your need to make data dynamic.

**Step 2 -** Customizing The Components

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

This command will publish the Markdown mail components to the resources/views/vendor/mail directory. The mail directory will contain an html and a text directory, each containing their respective representations of every available component. You are free to customize these components however you like.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#customizing-the-components

**Step 3 -** Customizing The CSS

After exporting the components, the `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes` directory will contain a `default.css` file. You may customize the CSS in this file and your styles will automatically be converted to inline CSS styles within the HTML representations of your Markdown mail messages.

If you would like to build an entirely new theme for Laravel's Markdown components, you may place a CSS file within the `html/themes` directory. After naming and saving your CSS file, update the theme option of your application's `config/mail.php` configuration file to match the name of your new theme.

To customize the theme for an individual mailable, you may set the $theme property of the mailable class to the name of the theme that should be used when sending that mailable.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#customizing-the-css

Answer (score 1):

I think you have only one way: you may customize the CSS in `default.css` file after exporting the mail components. Your styles will automatically be in-lined within the HTML representations of your Markdown mail messages.

**Step 1**: Publishing the mail components

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

**Step 2**: In `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes`, you customize `default.css` file.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#customizing-the-components

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that as this is an E-Mail not all of the CSS properties can be applied, at least not the modern ones.

You may try to publish the markdown styles with

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

And take a look at the generated style.css for the markdown mail. From here, you may change things like the background color, or buttons color. (Things like hover, or animations, or too complex style properties may not work).

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue before. You have to add the css codes in each mail template separately. Adding .css file's relative url in the template will look good when you see it in the local machine as view, but will break when it is sent as email. Css files don't render in emails. I had to add the css codes inside the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416123/css-not-loading-in-laravel-5-sent-email) you can encounter issues with some mail clients not handling properly external CSS files.

Check about [Laravel Markdown mail components & customization](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#customizing-the-components)

> After exporting the components, the resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes directory will contain a default.css file. You may customize the CSS in this file and your styles will automatically be converted to inline CSS styles within the HTML representations of your Markdown mail messages.

You could also use something like [laravel-mail-css-inliner](https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner) to "automatically" inline the the CSS file's content in the template render.

From readme:

> Most email clients won't render CSS (on a `<link>` or a `<style>`). The solution is inline your CSS directly on the HTML.

Do you see an HTML `<link>` to your CSS file in the mail body, or do you already have your CSS inlined into the body (and so it may be an issue with CSS syntax or tag syntax)?